# Php code writing issue in search engine

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, search-engine

Trying to create pagination with search query.Everything working fine,here error occurs,i'm not able to use `$page` to search.
Want like this in browser:

```
search.php?page=what+i+search where it equals to searched query
```

Code working properly(without query):

```
for ($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
{
?><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $b." ";?></a> <?php
}
?>
```

Tried like this:

```
for ($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
echo " <a href='search.php?page=“.stripslashes($page).”'> </a>";
?>
```

and like this:

```
for ($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
echo " <a href='search.php?page=$page&submit=$b'> </a>";
?>
```

Here `$page` is name in simple html form,see:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<b>Enter Search Term:</b> <input type="text" name="page" >
    <br>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Pls help,i want to include search query in pagination.

Comment: You're using the parameter `page` both for the search term and the page index. Change the search term to `term` or `query` or `q` or something common like that. Also, make sure you get your escaping right. `stripslashes` is not good enough. Use `htmlspecialchars`. Right now your website is open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Error is nothing shown when using my tried code,just give undefined submit when i'm using to process it.

Comment: @Halcyon,i tried what you saying but not worked.

Comment: If nothing shows you're likely getting an error. Make sure you've got error reporting turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's built in function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode $page value correctly.

Alternatively you can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build query string dynamicly:

```
$searchTerm = 'foo bar'; // it can be empty 

$queryData = $searchTerm ? ['search' => $searchTerm] : [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {
    $queryData['page'] = $i;
    $href = 'search.php?' . http_build_query($queryData);
    echo " <a href='$href'>$i</a>";
}
```

Comment: That is not a solution,these ectra thing i can do.Pls suggest real help.

Comment: I added another solution

Answer (score 0):

There are two variables that you need to keep track of:

- What page are you currently on
- The search term

This means that your final url should look something like this:

```
search.php?search=words&page=2
```

If you loop through your `$_GET` variables, you will see entries for both `$_GET['search']` and `$_GET['page']`. Your code should also have something that specifies the page a `1` if it is not set.

Your form can stay the same. However, when building the page links, you should do the following:

```
for($p=1;$p<=$maxPages;$p++) {
    echo '<a href="search.php?search=';
    echo urlencode($_GET['search']);  // urlencode() escapes spaces and other special characters
    echo '&page=' . $p;
    echo '">' . $p . '</a>';
}
```